# Can inserted and deleted contain data from a hybrid operation?

Tags: sql, sql-server

One caveat of using the inserted and deleted tables is that they can both be empty.  Are there any other catchya's I should be aware of?  For instance, can the inserted table contain new records as well as updated records?

I am relying on this logic to detect the action in a trigger:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted) SET @operation = 'U'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted) SET @operation = 'I'
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted) SET @operation = 'D'
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted) SET @operation = 'X'
```

EDIT:

This is my solution to the audit trail problem.  It has been tested on one MERGE statement that inserts, fake updates, real updates, and deletes.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[LogInsertEditDelete]
ON [dbo].[<TableToAudit>]
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

--You will need to change @table to match the table to be audited
DECLARE @table VARCHAR(50)
SELECT @table = '<TableToAudit>'

-- date and user
DECLARE @updatedBy VARCHAR(50),
        @timestamp DateTime
SELECT @updatedBy = SYSTEM_USER,
       @timestamp = GETDATE()

-- Action, U = update, I = insert, D = delete
DECLARE @insertedCount int, 
        @deletedCount int
SET @insertedCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted)
SET @deletedCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deleted)

-- handle no action
IF @insertedCount = 0 AND @deletedCount = 0 RETURN  

-- handle update
IF @insertedCount <> 0 AND @deletedCount <> 0
BEGIN
    INSERT Audit (Type, TableName, UpdateDate, UpdatedBy, PK1)
    SELECT
        'U', 
        @table,
        @timestamp,
        @updatedBy,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), i.Id)
    FROM
        (SELECT Id, BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) Version FROM inserted) i
        INNER JOIN
        (SELECT Id, BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) Version FROM deleted) d
        ON i.Id = d.Id
    WHERE
        i.Version <> d.Version  

    RETURN      
END

-- handle deletes and inserts
INSERT Audit (Type, TableName, UpdateDate, UpdatedBy, PK1)
SELECT          
    CASE 
        WHEN i.Id IS NOT NULL AND d.Id IS NULL THEN 'I'
        WHEN i.Id IS NULL AND d.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 'D'
    END,
    @table,
    @timestamp,
    @updatedBy,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), COALESCE(i.Id, d.Id))
FROM inserted i 
        FULL OUTER JOIN
     deleted d 
        ON i.Id = d.Id
WHERE i.Id IS NULL OR
      d.Id IS NULL

END
```

This solution is not generic as the primary keys need to be spelled out for each table.

Comment: If you ran a MERGE statment and some records were updated and some were inserted, I would think that you would have both in the same inserted table (I have not tested this but it only makes logical sense.) and only the updated in the deleted table. So I don't think you can guarantee that all records in an operation are only one type of operation. Whay are you caring what type of operation it is? Maybe more on what you are trying to accomplish would help us help you.

Comment: I want to create a reliable audit trail.  With the help of other SOF members, I have created a query to find the updated ids.  If there's no guarantee that above logic works, I will need to create queries to find the newly inserted and deleted records.

Comment: @CandyChiu - For that case I normally just full outer join on the PK and check if `INSERTED.PK IS NULL` then it is a delete. If `DELETED.PK IS NULL` then it is an insert, otherwise it is an update. If the PK is itself updatable then this shows as an insert/delete but there is no way round that with triggers in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making my comment I got curious as to what would be in the inserted and deleted tables in a MERGE. Here is an example:

```
create table #test (test1 int identity not null, test2 varchar(34) null)


Insert into #test (test2)
values('test'), ('test2')

select * from #test


declare @output table(test1I int, test1D int, test2I varchar (34), test2D varchar (34))


MERGE #test AS target
USING (SELECT test1, test2 from #test ) AS source (test1, test2)
ON (target.test1 = source.test1)
WHEN MATCHED AND target.test1 = 1
    THEN UPDATE SET target.test2 = 'test3'
WHEN  MATCHED 
    THEN DELETE

OUTPUT inserted.test1, deleted.test1,  inserted.test2, deleted.test2 into @output ;

select 'Inserted/deleted contents', * from @output
select * from #test

Drop table #test
```

Something similar would happen if you were doing an insert or update.

If you need to know for each record, you might want to use a join and a case statment to figure out the status for each record rather than using scalar variables. Remember triggers operate on the whole set of records inserted/updated/deleted not one record at a time. So the use of scalar variables is often a clue that you are not doing things correctly. If you give us more of an example of what your trigger is going to do, then it would be easier to help you solve your problem as the current approach seems as if it will not cover all records.

Based on your comment above, perhaps this will give you some ideas on what to try within the trigger:

```
Insert dbo.Audittable (Id, NewField1Value, OldField1Value, ActionTaken, ActionDate, ActionUser)
select coalesce(inserted.id, deleted.id) as Id, inserted.field1 as newField1value, deleted.field1 as oldField1value ,
case when inserted.id is not null and deleted.id is not null then 'Update'
when inserted.id is not null and deleted.id is  null then 'Insert'
when inserted.id is null and deleted.id is not null then 'Delete'
End as ActionTaken
, getdate() as ActionDate
, system_user as ActionUser
from inserted
full outer join deleted on inserted.id = deleted.id
```

When testing your trigger, you will need the following test cases at a minimum:

- single record insert
- single record delete
- single record update
- mulitple record insert
- mulitple record delete
- mulitple record update
- mulitple record merge that does both inserts and deletes
- mulitple record merge that does both updates and deletes
- mulitple record merge that does both inserts and updates

You may need more depending on everything your trigger is going to do.

Comment: I ran a similar example, I don't see the inserts and updates are merged into one instance of the inserted & deleted table.

Comment: Your query works for the inserted and deleted merged into the updates.  but it doesn't work for the updates, as two copies of the same row may show up in the tables - one in deleted, one in inserted.

Comment: for updates, i need to check the values of every single column to make sure a REAL update has taken place.  the query may pick up some fake ones.  i also ran a test that inserts, updates, and deletes in a single MERGE statement, the inserted & deleted table captures changes of only one of the actions.  Seems to me my worry is not warranted.

Comment: I will post the solution after I test all the scenarios.

Comment: see the edits.  i like the solution except it is not generic.

Answer (score 1):

All 4 cases are possible. Notably "both" in case of an update and "none" in case the DML statement did not modify any rows.

This last condition can be detected cheaper that with an `EXISTS` query:

```
if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    return
```

You can restructure your `EXIST`-check a bit so that each table is only queries once in order to improve efficiency.

Comment: How would you access `inserted`/`deleted` from a stored proc?

Comment: can the inserted table contain new records as well as updated records?  i would have missed the inserted columns if i solely rely on the above logic.

Comment: @MartinSmith, how true! I deleted that paragraph.

Comment: @CandyChiu in case of an update the inserted table contains the new row versions and the deleted table contains the old versions.